# Select/Mask different column index in every row

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch I have a multi-dimensional tensor, call it X

```
X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], ...]
```

Now I would like to select a different column index for each row like so

```
indices = [[0], [1], [0], [2], ...]
# now I expect following values to be returned:
[[1], [5], [7], [12], ...]
```

also I would like to achieve the opposite so that for the given indices I get

```
[[2, 3], [4, 6], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

Is there a "simple" way to achieve this without a for loop? I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact the [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) function performs exactly this.

For example

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
indices = torch.tensor([[0], [1], [0], [2]])
a.gather(1, indices)
```

will exactly return

```
tensor([[ 1],
        [ 5],
        [ 7],
        [12]])
```

I do not require the opposite anymore but for this I would propose just creating a mask with all ones and then setting the respective indices of the "gathering" tensor to 0 or just create a new "gathering" tensor which contains the respective opposite keys. For example:

```
indices_opposite = [np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a.size(1)), i) for i in indices.numpy()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easily done with numpy, it can convert forth and back if you need it for tensor

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
X2= X[np.arange(X.shape[0]),[0,1,0,2]]
X3 = np.setdiff1d(X, X2).reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1]-1)
```

EDIT

doing the same in gpu, working with tensors

```
import torch.tensor as tensor
import numpy as np

X = tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
X2= X[np.arange(X.shape[0]),[0,1,0,2]]

def allothers(X, num):
    return [x for x in range(X.shape[1]) if x not in [num]]


X3 = X[ [[x] for x in np.arange(X.shape[0])], [allothers(X, 0),allothers(X, 2),allothers(X, 1),allothers(X, 1)] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that I am on a GPU and would like to keep my data there.