# From a 2D tensor, return a 1D tensor by selecting 1 column per row

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a 2D tensor and a 1D tensor:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

out = torch.randn((16,2))
target = torch.tensor([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

For each row of `out`, I want to select the corresponding column as indexed by `target`. Thus, my output will be a `(16,1)` tensor. I tried the solution mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58937071

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-50d103c3b56c>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    out.gather(1, target)
RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to apply [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html), the two tensors must have the same number of dimensions. As such you should unsqueeze an additional dimension on `target` *in last position*:

```
>>> out.gather(1, target[:,None])
tensor([[-1.1258],
        [-0.4339],
        [ 0.6920],
        [-2.1152],
        [ 0.3223],
        [ 0.3500],
        [ 1.2377],
        [ 1.1168],
        [-1.6959],
        [ 0.7935],
        [ 0.5988],
        [-0.3414],
        [ 0.7502],
        [ 0.1835],
        [ 1.5863],
        [ 0.9463]])
```

Comment: To add legibility:

out.gather(dim=1,index=target.unsqueeze(1))